# Entity Framework 6 - Entity count correlation with memory use

Tags: entity-framework

I am doing some research into memory use on our Web Servers. We are hitting just shy of 1 gig of memory used when loading just our Sign In page. After a lot of debugging and removing as much as possible from the solution I can see an explosion of memory use on our very first query from the database.

We have around 180 Entities in our Db Context. We are using SQL Server as our storage mechanism and are using something like a repo pattern for reading from the database (we call it a Reader). The baseline of memory use just before querying the database for the first time is around 100 Mb

Some of the items I have tried include not using the reader and going after the DbContext without any additional extension methods which only delayed the initial explosion of memory. I also wondered if maybe extra memory was being used to map the DbContext like it does on the initial query and I generated a file and had it read from it instead of mapping and didn't notice any real drop in memory use. I also ensured that we are disposing after each read and only having 1 DbContext per unit of work (in this case loading the Sign In page)

Finally after quite a bit of effort I stripped the solution down to only the Entities needed to load the Signin Page (like 3-4 Entities) and then I saw a HUGE drop in memory use. Not quite as much as I wanted but only a couple hundred meg jump in memory use.

So the question is what is the correlation in Entity Count to the memory use of the DbContext? Perhaps we are doing something wrong with our entities.

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler?  EG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/analyze-memory-usage?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

By default, an EF DbContext will maintain a reference to every entity that it loads. This means that a DbContext that is left "alive" for a significant amount of time will continually consume memory as new entities are requested. This is one reason the general advice for EF Contexts is to keep them as short-lived as possible.

The number of entity definitions and relationships a context is configured to work with can have a bearing on EF performance including memory use, but the bulk of the memory usage will be from entities being loaded and tracked. Breaking up a DbContext into smaller contexts to track a subset of entities can be useful for larger systems to bump initialization and query performance. It also accommodates defining multiple entity definitions per table, such as detailed entities for things like updates and stripped down summary entities for searches and other basic operations.

The best tool to avoid excessive memory use in an application is to leverage projection wherever possible. This can be a bugbear when working with Repository patterns where the default behaviour is to return entities and specifically collections of entities.

For example, if I have a need to display a list of orders and I need to display the products in each order along with the quantity, as well as the customer name given a structure similar to:

```
Order (OrderId, Number, CreatedDate)
  -> OrderStatus (OrderStatusId, Name)
  -> Customer (CustomerId, Name)
  -> OrderLines (OrderLineId, Quantity)
    -> Product (ProductId, Name)
```

I might have a Repository that can return an `IEnumerable<Order>` and have dealt with a way to tell it what to eager load, maybe even included a complex `Expression<Func<Order>>` to pass in search criteria for a "New" order status that ends up executing the following against the DbContext:

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .Include(x => x.OrderStatus)
    .Include(x => x.Customer)
    .Include(x => x.OrderLines)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Product)
    .Where(x => x.OrderStatus.OrderStatusId == OrderStatuses.New)
    .ToList();
return orders;
```

Then this data would be passed to a view where we display the Order Number, Customer Name,  and list the Product Names along with the Quantity from the associated OrderLine. The view can be provided these entities and extract the necessary fields, however we have loaded and tracked *all* fields of the related entities into the DbContext and into memory.

The alternative is to project to a ViewModel, a POCO containing just the fields we need:

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderSummaryViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderLineSummaryViewModel> OrderLines { get; set; } = new List<OrderLineSummaryViewModel>();
}
[Serializable]
public class OrderLineSummaryViewModel
{
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

now when we query the data, instead of returning `IEnumerable<Order>`, we return `IQueryable<Order>`. We can also do away with all complexity around passing what to eager load, filtering, sorting, and pagination. Consumers can refine the query as they see fit. The repository method becomes a simple:

```
IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersByStatus(params OrderStatuses[] orderStatuses)
{
    var query = context.Orders
        .Where(x => orderStatuses.Contains(x => x.OrderStatus.OrderStatusId);
    return query;
}
```

Then the caller projects this result into the ViewModel using `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo`:

```
var orders = Repository.GetOrdersByStatus(OrderStatuses.New)
    .Select(x => new OrderSummaryViewModel
    {
       OrderId = x.OrderId,
       OrderNumber = x.Number,
       CustomerId = x.Customer.CustomerId,
       CustomerName = x.Customer.Name,
       OrderLines = x.OrderLines
           .Select(ol => new OrderLineSummaryViewModel
           {
               OrderLineId = ol.OrderLineId,
               ProductLineId = ol.Product.ProductId,
               ProductName = ol.Product.Name,
               Quantity = ol.Quantity
           }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

The key differences here is that we now do not have the DbContext loading or tracking all of the associated orders, order lines, customer, products, etc. Instead it generates a query that will just pull back the fields projected into the view model. The memory footprint only grows by the amount of data we actually need rather than all of the entities and details we don't need.

Loading entities should be reserved for cases where we want to update data. For cases where we just want to read data, projection is very useful to reduce the memory footprint. One consideration I believe many teams have around loading and passing around entities /w longer lived DbContexts or the hassle of detaching and reattaching entities is to leverage caching and avoid DB Round-Trips.  IMO this is a poor reason for loading and passing around entities as it results in more memory usage, leaves systems vulnerable to tampering, easily leads to performance issues /w lazy loading, and also can result in stale data overwrites since cached entities in the DbContext are not automatically refreshed from their data.

Comment: Interesting, One of the thoughts I had with that much memory use is "Is this thing tracking all the things or what's going on here?"

So perhaps it is but I am unsure how to tell if it is? I can say for sure that its only querying against the DB for the one entity when it consumes a lot of memory.

How can you tell what the DbContext is currently tracking?

Comment: One way is to check the various DbSet.Local counts:  I.e. `context.As.Local.Count(); context.Bs.Local.Count(),` etc. to build a picture how many entities are presently tracked. I would look also at running a profiler against the DB to see how many queries are being run as code can trip lazy loading resulting in more tracked entities beyond the single/set of entities you might initially load.

Comment: Ok I was able to take a look at this. I don't have whatever As or Bs is on my DbContext but I did take a look at the Change Tracker right after I hit the database for the first time and I don't have any entities that are tracked. This is expected as our Reader uses the extension method AsNoTracking.

Also keep in mind that this is the first Db hit on load of the site so I would doubt the single record that is returned would eat up hundreds of Mb of memory even if the DbContext isn't disposed right after (I didn't see any noticeable difference when I did or didn't).

Comment: Sorry, As/Bs just refers to the various DbSets you have defined in your DbContext. `AsNoTracking` would prevent the DbContext from holding onto references. Definition mappings will use some space.